# If statement within for statement is only outputting the print statement of the else portion even though conditions met in if and elif parts

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

I am trying to get an if/else statement to run in a for loop. Despite the argument meeting the criteria for all statements above it, the output is the else portion.  Here is my code:

```
import string

print(string.ascii_lowercase)
print(string.ascii_uppercase)
print(string.ascii_letters)
print(string.digits)
print(string.punctuation)

my_string = '4n%$P9'
  
for index in range(0, len(my_string), 1):
  if my_string in string.ascii_lowercase:
    print("'{}' is a lowercase letter.".format(my_string))
  elif my_string in string.ascii_uppercase:
    print("'{}' is an uppercase letter.".format(my_string))
  elif my_string in string.digits: 
    print("'{}' is a digit in arabic.".format(my_string))
  elif my_string in string.punctuation:
    print("'{}' is a punctuation mark.".format(my_string))
  else:
    print("Does not compute.")
```

The output is this:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
0123456789
!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~
Does not compute.
Does not compute.
Does not compute.
Does not compute.
Does not compute.
Does not compute.
```

I'm not getting a syntax error so I am wondering, am I not using the correct keywords? Is the logic out of order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem isn't with the `if` statements so much as your `for` loop.  It looks like you want to iterate over each character in `my_string` and test it separately, not test `my_string` all at once:

```
for c in my_string:
    if c in string.ascii_lowercase:
        print(f"'{c}' is a lowercase letter.")
    elif c in string.ascii_uppercase:
        print(f"'{c}' is an uppercase letter.")
    elif c in string.digits: 
        print(f"'{c}' is a digit in arabic.")
    elif c in string.punctuation:
        print(f"'{c}' is a punctuation mark.")
    else:
        print(f"'{c}' does not compute.")
```

prints:

```
'4' is a digit in arabic.
'n' is a lowercase letter.
'%' is a punctuation mark.
'$' is a punctuation mark.
'P' is an uppercase letter.
'9' is a digit in arabic.
```

Note that printing `c` as part of the "does not compute" message allows you to see what character didn't compute -- if you had done this with `my_string` in your original code, you would have seen:

```
'4n%$P9' does not compute.
'4n%$P9' does not compute.
'4n%$P9' does not compute.
'4n%$P9' does not compute.
'4n%$P9' does not compute.
'4n%$P9' does not compute.
```

which would have been a good clue as to what the problem was!

Answer (score 0):

You are checking whether the entire string is a substring of each of the constants from the `string` module. You want to perform that check for *each character* in the string, like so:

```py
import string

my_string = '4n%$P9'
  
for char in my_string:
  if char in string.ascii_lowercase:
    print("'{}' is a lowercase letter.".format(char))
  elif char in string.ascii_uppercase:
    print("'{}' is an uppercase letter.".format(char))
  elif char in string.digits: 
    print("'{}' is a digit in arabic.".format(char))
  elif char in string.punctuation:
    print("'{}' is a punctuation mark.".format(char))
  else:
    print("Does not compute.")
```

This outputs:

```
'4' is a digit in arabic.
'n' is a lowercase letter.
'%' is a punctuation mark.
'$' is a punctuation mark.
'P' is an uppercase letter.
'9' is a digit in arabic.
```

Answer (score -2):

You are trying to compare if an entire string is in `string.ascii_lowercase`, not just the letters, you need to actually run `my_string[index]`.

```py
import string

print(string.ascii_lowercase)
print(string.ascii_uppercase)
print(string.ascii_letters)
print(string.digits)
print(string.punctuation)

my_string = '4n%$P9'
  
for index in range(0, len(my_string), 1):
  if my_string[index] in string.ascii_lowercase:
    print("'{}' is a lowercase letter.".format(my_string[index]))
  elif my_string[index] in string.ascii_uppercase:
    print("'{}' is an uppercase letter.".format(my_string[index]))
  elif my_string[index] in string.digits: 
    print("'{}' is a digit in arabic.".format(my_string[index]))
  elif my_string[index] in string.punctuation:
    print("'{}' is a punctuation mark.".format(my_string[index]))
  else:
    print("Does not compute.")
```